# Why golang container in k8s show linear memory leak, but htop shows no leaks?

Tags: go, memory-leaks

I have a microservice written in golang.
It processes images and do other stuff.

In k8s it shows linear memory grow [image: k8s memory usage]

But in htop, it has stable memory usage. I tested it locally - also stable.
[image: htop usage]

I understand, k8s shows some different memory usage, but what is it? And how to release/free this memory from golang?
There is no large heap. GC runs normally and I even run `debug.FreeOSMemory()` every 10 seconds from Go.

```
# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
cache 3095613440
rss 189210624
rss_huge 0
shmem 0
mapped_file 1548288
dirty 15630336
writeback 0
pgpgin 7268911
pgpgout 6466952
pgfault 6519532
pgmajfault 15
inactive_anon 0
active_anon 189140992
inactive_file 628293632
active_file 2467319808
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 8589934592
total_cache 3095613440
total_rss 189210624
total_rss_huge 0
total_shmem 0
total_mapped_file 1548288
total_dirty 15630336
total_writeback 0
total_pgpgin 7268911
total_pgpgout 6466952
total_pgfault 6519532
total_pgmajfault 15
total_inactive_anon 0
total_active_anon 189140992
total_inactive_file 628293632
total_active_file 2467319808
total_unevictable 0
```

Comment: So, it was growing up to ~4Gb, and then fall to 341Mb. Why? What happened?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cache is consuming more memory (3GB as of now), which could be reason for exceeding the memory limit.
And it shouldn't OOM at 4GB as you have memory limit at 8GB.